# Expectation of a combination of random variables.

Tags: probability

Assume that $\xi_i, i=1, \dots, n$ are independent identically distributed  discrete random variables. What is an expectation of 
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \xi_i^2}{\left( \sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i \right)^2}$$

Note:
It is possible to show that $E\frac{\sum_i a_i \xi_i}{\sum_i \xi_i} = \frac{\sum_i a_i}{n}$.

Comment: It would be helpful if you describe, or give a reference to, how the result in your last sentence was obtained.  Are the $\xi_i$ i.i.d. _Bernoulli_ random variables (and _not arbitrary_ discrete random variables) by any chance?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Simply by symmetry (and no need to specify the distribution, only to assume that $\xi_i\gt0$ almost surely, to ensure the denominator is almost surely nonzero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation of $\eta_n^{-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\xi_i$ is $\theta_1\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i$, where $\theta_1=E[\eta_n^{-1}\xi_1]$ and $\eta_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\xi_i$. Note that, by symmetry, $n\theta_1=E[\eta_n^{-1}\xi_1]+E[\eta_n^{-1}\xi_2]+\cdots+E[\eta_n^{-1}\xi_n]=1$ hence $\theta_1=n^{-1}$, irrespectively of the distribution of $\xi_1$. This yields the result recalled in the question.

Likewise, the answer here is $\theta_2\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i$, where $\theta_2=E[\eta_n^{-2}\xi_1^2]$.
Note that $n^2\theta_2\geqslant1$ by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and $n\theta_2\lt1$ for every $n\geqslant2$ since $n\theta_2+n(n-1)\varphi=1$, where $\varphi=E[\eta_n^{-2}\xi_1\xi_2]$. However, there is no reason to expect that $\theta_2$ is independent of the distribution of $\xi_1$, nor that it has a simple form in general.